# How to remove an icon from launchpad

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, matlab

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (Standard Gnome). I recently was using app designer on MATLAB when all of a sudden, I started seeing an icon in my launchpad (image link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PALF.png)). I want to remove it but I can't see the option even when I use the `super` + `alt` + `right-click` shortcut. I tried searching for a desktop file in the following folders
`/usr/share/applications`
`/usr/local/share/applications`
`~/.local/share/applications`
But I couldn't find the *.desktop* file.

My MATLAB R2017b is installed in the directory `/usr/local/MathWorks/MATLAB/R2017b`.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PALF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried opening MATLAB and moving a file that was present in the directory (which was being shown by the icon), now the icon is gone.